# Unable to save sharepreference in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to call `saveName` but nothing is being saved. And also I can see that commit is deprecated so how do you save values within `SharedPreferences`

```
Future saveName(bool isloggedIn,String passwordval) async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setBool("is_logged_in ", isloggedIn);
    sharedPreferences.setString("password ", passwordval);
    sharedPreferences.commit();
  }

  getCredential() async {
    print("###coming inside getcredentials");
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      isloggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBool("is_logged_in");
      if (isloggedIn != null) {
        if (isloggedIn) {
          print("###isloggedin=true");
          passwordController.text = sharedPreferences.getString("password");
        } else {
          print("###isloggedin=false");
          passwordController.clear();
          sharedPreferences.clear();
        }
      } else {
        isloggedIn = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: It is, as @nonybrighto said, definitely because when you set the data in the first method there is whitespace after `is_logged_in`

Answer (score 0):

check the key you used in creating your preference and the one used in accessing it. They are different. `sharedPreferences.setBool("is_logged_in ", isloggedIn)` should be `await sharedPreferences.setBool("is_logged_in", isloggedIn)`. Remove the whitespace in `"is_logged_in "` and `"password "`. Your preferences will be saved even if you don't include `sharedPreferences.commit();`